# Retriving url from database and declare to input type image

Tags: php, forms, image, input

`<div class="form-group"> <input type="file" name="Upload" id="Upload"> </div>`

I do have a submit button. While updating an image, I want to retrieve URL link *"IMG/4.jpg"* from database to default value of input.  `<?PHP echo $opened['IMG'];?>`is my PHP code. I want to show *something* by default while I am **updating** the post!.

We have `<input type="file">` so it will show a button for image upload and the name of image on the right.
For default value there is no any image value. When i press the button i can choose image from file, and it will show name of chosen image. So here is question: how can i give image name from PHP since it has value in database like "IMG/4.jpg"?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I tried to edit to make it more clear, if I understand you want to show a default value on your file input field?  For more info on asking questions, take a look at [ask].

Comment: Yes exactly. And after than update data base with that value. Since im making edit page form.

Comment: This shouldn't have a default because the name that shows should be the name of a file on their computer, not the name of the file on your server.  If you want to show the user what image they have, you should show the picture next to the input field instead; the name you have it stored under does not tell them anything.

Comment: Hmm, it makes sense now. Thank you!